# MySQL nested select: am I able to use any data from outer select?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Let's imagine I have the following table `users`:

```
id name
1  John
2  Mike
3  Max
```

And table `posts`

```
id author_id date       title
1  1         2014-12-12 Post 2
2  1         2014-12-10 Post 1
3  2         2014-10-01 Lorem ipsum
...and so on
```

And I'd like to have a query containing the following data:

- user name
- number of user's posts within last week
- number of user's posts within last month

I can do it just for each individual user (with id 1 in the following example):

```
SELECT
  `name`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts`
   WHERE
     `author` = 1 AND
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) < 7*24*3600) AS `posts7`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts`
   WHERE
     `author` = 1 AND
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) < 30*24*3600) AS `posts30`
FROM `users`
WHERE `id` = 1
```

I suspect that MySQL will allow do this for all users within one query if I could exchange the data between inner and outer SELECT's. I probably using wrong words, but I really hope that people here will understand my needs and I will have some help.

Comment: Why not use a join between posts and name and two case statements to determine if post is < 7 days or less than 30 days then aggregate the results...

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT the final SQL but gives you the jist...

```
Select name, sum(case when datewithin7 then 1 else 0 end) as posts7, 
             sum(case when datewithin30 then 1 else 0 end) as posts30
from name
left join posts on name.id = posts.nameid
GROUP BY name.
```

Note you need the group by. but I don't have the time to put the case statement together...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
  SELECT
    `name`,
    sum(IF(`date` between DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY) and now() , 1, 0) as posts7,
    sum(IF(`date` between DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 30 DAY) and now() , 1, 0) as posts30
  FROM
    `users` as u, posts as p
  WHERE
    u.id = p.author_id
  GROUP BY
    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly aggregating a non-nested query is the way to solve the problem although both Benni and xQbert have written unbounded queries - which, while satisfying the objective, are very innefficient. Consider (adapted from Benni's answer):

```
SELECT `name`
, SUM(IF(
   `date` between DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY) and now() 
   , 1
   , 0) as posts7
, SUM(IF(
   p.author_id IS NULL 
   , 0
   , 1) as posts30
FROM `users` as u
LEFT JOIN posts as p
ON u.id = p.author_id
AND p.date > NOW()-INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY name
```

Note that NOT using the conversion to a UNIX timestamp allows the database to use an index (if available) to resolve the query.

However there are scenarios where it is more effective / appropriate to use a nested query. So although it's not the best solution to **this** problem:

```
SELECT
`name`
, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM `posts` AS p7
   WHERE p7.author = users.id 
   AND p7.`date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS `posts7`
, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM `posts` AS p30
   WHERE p30.author = users.id 
   AND p30.`date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS `posts30`
FROM `users` 
WHERE `id` = 1
```